# Having issues adding items to an array within promise

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, promise, async-await

I am making a social media like site where users can follow each other. In one of my routes, I want to loop through the current users following array, which is an array of ids, find those users posts and add them to one big array, then sort the posts by date. The problem is that the array is getting sent to the client before the posts are added to it. Not sure if i need some sort of async function or what.

my route to get posts

```
const express = require('express')
const user = require("../models/user')
const router = express.Router()

router.get("/api/:username/following/posts", (req, res) => {
    let following = [...req.user.following, req.user._id]
    let posts = [], i;
    for(i = 0; i < following.length; i++){
        User.findById(following[i]).populate("posts")
            .then(user => {
                for(let b = 0; b < user.posts.length; b++){
                    posts.push(user.posts[b])
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
    console.log(posts) // returns []
    res.json(posts) 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using async/await

```
router.get("/api/:username/following/posts", async (req, res) => {
    const following = [...req.user.following, req.user._id]
    const posts = [];
    for(let f of following){
        const user = await User.findById(f).populate("posts");
        posts.push(...user.posts);
    }
    console.log(posts)
    res.json(posts) 
})
```

using Promises only

```
router.get("/api/:username/following/posts", (req, res) => {
    const following = [...req.user.following, req.user._id];
    Promise.all(following.map(f => User.findBy(f).populate("posts")))
    .then(users => {
        const posts = users.map(({posts}) => posts).flat();
        console.log(posts);
        res.json(posts);
    });
})
```

The major difference is that the Promises only code will call User.findBy in parallel, whereas the async/await will call those one by one in sequence (don't worry, the order is maintained in promise version as well)

If there's a problem with calling findBy in parallel and you still don't want to use async/await, you can do it like:

```
router.get("/api/:username/following/posts", (req, res) => {
    const following = [...req.user.following, req.user._id];
    Promise.all(following.reduce((p, f) => p.then(results => User.findBy(f).populate("posts").then(user => [...results, user])), Promise.resolve([])))
    .then(users => {
        const posts = users.map(({posts}) => posts).flat();
        console.log(posts);
        res.json(posts);
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use async/await, or you can just move your res.json call into the .then

Comment: since `.then` is called once for each follower, that won't work at all

Comment: True. I wasn’t paying close enough attention.